# Есть ли нюансы при использовании бесплатного плана в Firebase?

Tags: vue.js, firebase

1. Достаточно ли базового бесплатного плана к примеру для приложение (Vue.js+Firebase) внутреннего пользования, для малого бизнеса (ведение учета, графики зависимостей и т.д.), в плане бд, хостинга, количества запросов и т.д. ?
2. На сколько вообще распространена практика использования бесплатного плана Firebase для продакшен ?
3. Есть ли какие-то нюансы при использовании в продакшен такого плана ?
4. Достаточно ли являются защищенными данные в БД ? Нужна ли для защиты дополнительная утилита?

Буду благодарен за ответы и советы из личного опыта!